# [Golang][Linux] - How to get all open files by current user

Tags: linux, go

I want to delete some logs when logs size exceed quota, But I need to check if the log is opening before delete it.

How to get all open files by current user?

Comment: [lsof](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lsof&sektion=8&manpath=freebsd-release-ports)

Comment: by parse "/proc", I can get all opening file. I want to know whether there is a better way

Comment: just check my first comment and here is [some examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/lsof-command-examples) and btw, you can use [logrotate](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=logrotate&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) to compress and archive the logs automatically, then delete it later (may be with a script)

Comment: Thanks bansi, I want to implement a agent that it will running on docker container environment, it cant't have too much process, also crontab

Comment: another option is you can safely remove lines from the top of the log file even if it is open, if your environment has `sed` or `tail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing /proc (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)...) is probably the most efficient way and is what `lsof` would do.

You could first scan all (numeric) directories to find processes running by your users, than in all such directories use the `/proc/`pid`/fd` directory.

BTW, you might not care and just remove these log files. The kernel will behave appropriately if it was opened.

But perhaps you should ask your sysadmin to setup [disk quotas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota). See [quota(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/quota.1.html) & [quotaon(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/quotaon.8.html).

Perhaps using & configuring [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you're bash scripting, `lsof` might fit your need. If you're interested in the user with username X, `lsof -uX` should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

by parse "/proc" get all open file:

```
func getOpenfiles() (openfiles map[string]bool) {
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir("/proc")
    openfiles = make(map[string]bool)
    for _, f := range files {
        m, _ := filepath.Match("[0-9]*", f.Name())
        if f.IsDir() && m {
            fdpath := filepath.Join("/proc", f.Name(), "fd")
            ffiles, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(fdpath)
            for _, f := range ffiles {
                fpath, err := os.Readlink(filepath.Join(fdpath, f.Name()))
                if err != nil {
                    continue
                }
                openfiles[fpath] = true
            }
        }
    }
    return openfiles
}
```